Icant use high chart in AdminLTE
I am using version 3 of AdminLTE and I want to use high chart in it, when I want to use pie charts, the labels are white and I could not change its style with css style and different methods. Is there a problem with the js version? How is the problem solved?

I tried different ways to change the style of the label, but I didn't get an answer


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

see this recent answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/78236858/3807365
